How to combine multiple rows of one column into two columns in SQL
Thanks for any help. I was trying to generate multiple rows at target side for each row of source as shown below. I am using pivot in SQL to generate rows and need help with a SQL statement to match target expected data:
SELECT
    ID, CODES, 1 AS seq
FROM 
    TBL
UNPIVOT 
    (CODES FOR CPT_CDD IN (COL_1_CD,COL_1_CD_1)) AS P 
WHERE 
   COL_1_CD IS NOT NULL AND COL_1_CD_1 IS NOT NULL

UNION

SELECT
    ID, CODES, 2 AS seq
FROM 
    TBL
UNPIVOT 
    (CODES FOR CPT_CDD IN (COL_2_CD, COL_2_CD_1)) 
WHERE 
    COL_2_CD IS NOT NULL AND COL_2_CD_1 IS NOT 

UNION

SELECT
    ID, CODES, 2 AS seq
FROM
    TBL
UNPIVOT 
    (CODES FOR CPT_CDD IN (COL_2_CD, COL_2_CD_1)) 
WHERE 
    ((COL_2_CD IS NULL AND COL_2_CD_1 IS NOT NULL) 
     OR (COL_2_CD IS NOT NULL AND COL_2_CD_1 IS NULL))

UNION

SELECT
    ID, CODES, 1 AS seq
FROM
    TBL
UNPIVOT 
    (CODES FOR CPT_CDD IN (COL_2_CD, COL_2_CD_1)) 
WHERE 
    ((COL_1_CD IS NULL AND COL_1_CD_1 IS NOT NULL) 
     OR (COL_1_CD IS NOT NULL AND COL_1_CD_1 IS NULL))

UNION

SELECT 
    ID, NULL AS CODES, 3 AS seq
FROM
    TBL
WHERE 
    (COL_1_CD IS NULL AND COL_1_CD_1 IS NULL 
     AND COL_2_CD IS NULL AND COL_2_CD_1 IS NULL);



Oracle or Teradata? Why have you tagged two different DBMS?

Modified the tags. Thanks

I don't understand where the expected result comes from. There is no Value 3 in the source for instance, but in the target it is there. Where does it come from?

My bad, Image was cropped. Modified it now . Apologies

Simply select the two columns that belong together and then use UNION to combine the two data sets and remove duplicates.
select col_1_cd   as col_1_cds, col_2_cd   as col_2_cds  from mytable
union
select col_1_cd_1 as col_1_cds, col_2_cd_1 as col_2_cds  from mytable
order by coalesce(col_1_cds, col_2_cds);


Sql worked as expected whenever i had four values in all 4 cols but not working if any column has null value . It adding additional null row in result set. I can tweak rest of the query. Thanks a lot for quick help. :)

That is weird. If only one column is null, it does not seem possible that the query produces a NULL|NULL row. Or maybe I don't understand what you mean. You can create a https://dbfiddle.uk/ to demonstrate this.
